# How to bind value property to the button visibility?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I need to style `UIButton` depends on values from two `textFields`:

```
Observable.combineLatest(loginProperty.asObservable(), passwordProperty.asObservable()) { _, _ in
    self.viewModel.isValid
}.bind(to: mainView.loginButton.rx.isValid).disposed(by: bag)
```

Also I need to style UIButton depends on value from **one text field**, and above solution doesn't work. Why? What is the simple way to do that?

Comment: AFAIK, combineLatest property is triggered when all the chained properties send at least one value, which in this case means when you type something inside both textFields, it will update loginButton isValid.

Comment: Can you share code what you had write in login and password observer

Comment: What are loginProperty and paswordProperty? Can you please share all of your code to better understand what you mean

Comment: @Bartłomiej Semańczyk you can use combinedLatest and BehaviorRelay to handle loginButton state. Added answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use combinedLatest to combine email and password to create `isButtonEnabled` `Observable` and bind the values to `BehaviorRelay`, then subscribe to `onNext` events from the `BehaviorRelay` and set values

```
func rxLogin() {

    let isValidPassword = username.rx.text.orEmpty
        .map { $0.count > 8 }
        .distinctUntilChanged()

    let isValidEmail = password.rx.text.orEmpty
        .map { $0.contains("@") }
        .distinctUntilChanged()

    let isButtonEnabled: Observable<Bool> = Observable.combineLatest(isValidEmail, isValidPassword) { $0 && $1 }.share()

    //option 1

    let submitButtonState: BehaviorRelay<Bool> = BehaviorRelay<Bool>(value: false)

    isButtonEnabled
        .bind(to: submitButtonState)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    submitButtonState
        .bind { (isEnabled) in
            self.loginButton.isEnabled = isEnabled
            self.loginButton.backgroundColor = isEnabled ? UIColor.green : UIColor.red
        }.disposed(by: disposeBag)

    //OR

    isButtonEnabled
        .subscribe(onNext: { (isValidCredentials) in
            self.loginButton.isEnabled = isValidCredentials
            self.loginButton.backgroundColor = isValidCredentials ? .green : .red
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As [Al_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1057689/al) mentioned in his comment, `combineLatest` will emit first next value when both streams will emit at least one value.

To style button depending on one of the text field rx properties:

- you can use side effects (ex: `.do(onNext: { ... })`)
- or just make another subscription to the property

Are you using any extension? As there is no property `isValid`, try to use `mainView.loginButton.rx.isHidden` if you want to change visibility of the button.